# How can I set the backround image height without cutting the image, just like responsive images?

Tags: css

I have applied set `background-image` on one of my `<div>` with the following properties below:

```
.mydiv-left {
     background: url(path to image) no-repeat center center fixed;
     height:auto; // also tried with 100%
     background-size:auto // also tried with "100%" and "100% 100%" as well as "cover"
}
```

This result is no image display, but when I set the height to this image, it cuts off the image. As image is of high resolution and I want it to fit in the smaller area of my div without removing any part/information.

Keep in mind that background image is dynamic and keep on changing for other divs within the loop.

Comment: you cant set dynamic height and width to background image. for dynamic height-width you have to use <img /> in div.

Comment: Yes I was doing it before but now my client requirements are to set it as background image on div rather than using image

Comment: could you please post the code or sent a js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for helping me out, I was able to get it done with the following below code:

```
mydiv {

  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 150px; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Main thing was last four lines that worked for me the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

CSS

```
.mydiv-left {
    background-image: url(path to image);
    height:(in px);
    width: (in px);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no repeat;
    background-position: center center;     
}
```

If you post the entire code it is easy to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

`<div>` without content/ height will result in 0 height. I guess that's why you can't see your image.

Give your `<div>` a size, and `background-size` should do its work.

http://jsfiddle.net/LsdDE/

```
.d1, .d2 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(https://www.google.com.tw/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
}

.d1 {
    background-size: auto 200px;
}

.d2 {
    background-size: 200px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest suggestion would be to give `min-height` to your div in pixels...  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mY8y/4/) , keeping your markup same, below is the CSS.

**CSS**

```
 .mydiv-left {
    background: url(http://www.wallng.com/images/2013/08/image-explosion-colors-background-beautiful-263613.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    color : #FFF;
    min-height:200px;    /*this is the key*/
    height:auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

if you give  `height:auto;`, it would scale the `div` to content height.
if you want to show the `div` anyway, `min-height` is a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
.mydiv-left {
    background-image: url(path to image);
    height:(in px);
    width: (in px);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no repeat;
    background-position: center center;     
}
```